# ToolTip with text + databinder.eval

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, c#-4.0

how can I add a tooltip to a asp:label with a value from the DB plus a text?

I currently have

```
Tooltip= '<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "ID") %> '
```

and it is successfully returning the ID `100` for example but I would like it to return `ID:100` . How can I concatenate the string ID with the result of Databinder.Eval?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this (C#) ...

```
Tooltip='<%# "ID:" + DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "ID") %>'
```